# Firestore push multiple keys to map without overwriting

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Current data in firestore

```
fruits: { apple: 20, orange: 10 }
```

Now how to add more fruits to the `fruits` field without overwriting `apple` and `orange`

Fruits to be added

```
fruits: { pineapple: 20, cherry: 10, banana: 10 }
```

Tried doing this but `apple` and `orange` gets **removed**

```
batch.update(fs.doc(`config/254868`), {
  fruits: fruits,
});
```

Comment: You need to use [dot notation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) to call out each individual nested field to update.  What you are doing right now is specifying an entirely new map to update the field called "fruits".